# Can a model learn from validation set?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have just joined in the AI concept and started to learn machine learning, I saw that we split the dataset into train, valid and testing set. I have read that valid set can be used to avoid overfitting and underfitting but I don't actually know why so maybe our model can learn from valid set but can't learn from testing set isn't it?

The concise answer about model can learn from valid and testing set.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is validation data used for in a Keras Sequential model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46308374/what-is-validation-data-used-for-in-a-keras-sequential-model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model does learn from neither the validation set nor the test set.

- You use the **validation set** to **validate results from training in regard to the algorithm and hyperparameters you choose**. The model does not «see» the data for actual training or is in any way trained on it.
- You use the **test set** after you finish tuning and training the model to **get an unaffected view of you models quality**. Again the model is not trained in any way on the test set.

Why don't we just use the test set for tuning and final assesment of the model?

We as data scientists tune hyperparameters. Therefore the validation data indirectly influences our model because it directly influences our design decisions. We nudge our model to work well with the validation data and that can possibly bring in a tilt. Only by using a third part of the data – the test set - we get this entirely neutral view on the final quality of the model.